# How to handle button click after another button click

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have created few buttons, when the first button is clicked by the user, then border of first button is changed to `red`, then only user can click's on second button.

> This program can log which second button pressed by the user and show
>   to the console.

***Later on , I want to change first button's background to second button's background.***

```
    box = new ResizeButton[]{
                    (ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.kotak1),
                    (ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.kotak2),
                    (ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.kotak3),
                    (ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.kotak4),
                    (ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.kotak5),
                    (ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.kotak6),
                    (ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.kotak7),
                    (ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.kotak8),
                    (ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.kotak9)
            };

            boxPlay = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};  // This is to identify player 1 or player 2 win


    box[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            box[currentButton].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_red));
            int changeWith;
            do {
                changeWith = selectedButton();
            }while (changeWith == -1);
            Log.d("TAG", "Change: " + changeWith);
    }

    private int selectedButton() {
            returnCode = -1;
            for(int i = 0; i < box.length;i++){
                final int selected = i;
                box[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(boxPlay[selected] == 0)
                            returnCode = selected;
                        else
                            invalidSelect();
                    }
                });
            }
            return returnCode;
    }
}
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

when I run this code I got error :

> Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because the touched
>   window has not finished processing the input events that were
>   previously delivered to it.)
>       Load: 1.68 / 1.09 / 0.72

How to solve this problem? Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: can you add a screenshot? not able to figure out what u are trying to say

`this selected button is turn with border red, then user can select another button.???`
this is not making sense at all.
And,
`boxPlay[selected] == 0` what is boxPlay??
what i understand is `press first button than only second button should be active and you want to long what is the second button`

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir, wait a minute.

Comment: check my question new question sir.

Comment: what if user want's select's the already selected button?

Comment: Its call invalidSelect function.

Answer (score 1):

just set a default color in All button on every button click.
then after set border color in clickable button. like below

```
    box[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setDefualtColor()
                    box[currentButton].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_red));
                    int changeWith;
                    do {
                        changeWith = selectedButton();
                    }while (changeWith == -1);
                    Log.d("TAG", "Change: " + changeWith);
                }


private void setDefualtColor(){
        for(int i = 0; i < box.length;i++){
            box[i].setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(baseActivity, R.drawable.defualt_color));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, the border is already work, but error happen when user select second button.

Comment: I think you should use a separate buttons instead of an array. it is easy and simple.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code if the last button !=0 it will return `invalidSelect()`, So return the value when `boxPlay[selected] == 0`.

```
private int selectedButton() {
        returnCode = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < box.length;i++){
            final int selected = i;
            box[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(boxPlay[selected] == 0)
                        return selected;
                    else
                       invalidSelect();
            }
        });
    }
    return returnCode;
```

Hope this works

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, but my invalidSelect is a void function.

Comment: Also, I can't return value from there. Its only show Toast message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53883710/7972699) is a good solution to add handle border.

  - As for the second part, save the instance of the button view in a variable and access it later on when other button is clicked.

    ```
       private int[] boxPlay = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};  // This is to identify player 1 or player 2 win

       private Button lastSelectedbutton = null //to store the current selected button instance to get the drawable and reset the button


       box[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        //this v is the current selected button view's instance


        // check here if button this is the second button or first
        if (lastSelectedbutton != null) {


            //means this is second button
            setUpSecondButton(v, lastSelectedButton);

            lastSelectedButton = null;

        } else {

            box[currentButton].setImageDrawable(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.border_red));
            lastSelectedButton = (Button) v;
            int changeWith;
            do {
                changeWith = selectedButton();
            } while (changeWith == -1);
            Log.d("TAG", "Change: " + changeWith);

        }

    }
    private void setUpSecondButton (Button secondButton, Button firstButton){
        //copy the drawable to second button and reset first button as per need.
        secondButton.setBackground(firstButton.getBackground())
        firstButton.setBackground(null)
    }
    private int selectedButton () {
        returnCode = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
            final int selected = i;
            box[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (boxPlay[selected] == 0)
                        returnCode = selected;
                    else
                        invalidSelect();
                }
            });
        }
        return returnCode;
    }

    }
    ```

Answer (score -1):

Xml:

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:onClick="btn1"/>
<Button
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:onClick="btn2"/>
```

Java:

```
public void btn1(View v){
   //perform any task on btn1 click
   btn2(v);//btn2 click on 1st button click
}

public void btn2(View v){
   //perform any task on btn2 click
}
```

or you can perform a click by button id

```
box[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        box[currentButton].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_red));
        int changeWith;
        do {
            changeWith = selectedButton();
        }while (changeWith == -1);
        Log.d("TAG", "Change: " + changeWith);
        box[i+1].performClick();
        box[6].performClick();//or

}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer sir, check my new question.